# converting Python code to C code

Tags: python, python-itertools

I was trying to convert the itertools.product() python's fonction to C code:

```
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        yield tuple(prod)
```

to C code, but I didn't understand this particular instruction:

```
result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
```

could anyone explain it for me ?
thank's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ashish pointed out, it's a list comprehension. In short list comprehensions are basically just a one-liner for a loop with an optional conditional statement (or many conditional statements for that matter) that returns an array.

```
[ expression for item in list if conditional ]
```

is equivalent to

```
for item in list:
if conditional:
    expression
```

List comprehensions will return an array of all expression results in that loop.

```
result = [ x+1 for x in [0,1,2] ]
```

would in turn execute 0+1, save the value in an array, then do the same with 1+1 and 2+1. Finally the result would be [1,2,3]

Answer (score 0):

It's a [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). It is equivalent to the following -

```
result = []
for x in result:
    for y in pool:
        result.append(x+[y])
```